# How do I check if a pointer points to NULL?

Tags: c++, c, null

The title may be a little bit of a misnomer... just because I'm not sure if my char pointer is pointing to NULL, or if it's just pointing to a char array of size 0.

So I have

```
char* data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
```

And I want to check if data is null (or is length < 1). I've tried:

```
if(strlen(data)<1)
```

but I get an error:

```
==24945== Invalid read of size 1
==24945==    at 0x8048BF9: main (in /cpp.cgi)
==24945==  Address 0x1 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I've also tried

```
if(data == NULL)
```

but with the same result.

What's going on here? I've already tried cout with the data, and that works fine. I just can't seem to check if it's null or empty.

I realize these are two different things (null and empty). I want to know which one data would be here, and how to check if it's null/empty.

Comment: Side note: You should use `const char*`, not `char*`. From [the (C++) docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/): `The string pointed by the pointer returned by this function shall not be modified by the program.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With getenv, you have to handle both cases! (Yay!) If the environment variable is not set, then the function returns NULL. If it is set, then you get a pointer to the value it's set to, which may be empty. So:

```
const char* data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
if (data != NULL && data[0] != '\0') {
    // Variable is set to value with length > 0
    // ...
}
```

Obviously, you need to check if it's NULL *before* attempting to determine its length or read any of the characters it points to -- this is why the two conditions in the above `if` are ordered the way they are.

Comment: This can be greatly reduced to `if (data && *data) { ... }`

Comment: @Philip: Yes, yes it could. But which one is more readable? That's a matter of opinion. Use what you like best! My personal preference would be `if (data && data[0] != '\0')`. I added the `!= NULL` to make my answer clearer.

Comment: @Cameron: Some people on SO claim that there are platforms where NULL != 0. On other hand *"A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;"*. Which means that both ways of checking are valid.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you'd check with something like this. The first part checks the pointer for null, the second checks for an empty string by checking the first character for the null terminator at the end of every string.

```
if (data == NULL || data[0] == 0)
```

Your problem looks like some specific interaction between `getenv` and `strlen` that isn't standard.

Comment: `getenv` returns a pointer to a normal null-terminated C-string. `strlen` is built for those sort of strings.

Comment: @Cameron: Can you imagine zero-length C-string that doesn't start with `\0`?

Comment: I think `!data[0]` will be shorter.

Comment: @Cameron: Then there's no reason to use strlen.

Comment: @SigTerm: Shorter, yes, but arguably less meaningful than `data[0] == '\0'`. Note `!*data` is even shorter! :-) I'm not using `strlen`, I was simply pointing out to Mark that that's not what's causing the problem with a string obtained from `getenv`.

Comment: @Cameron, based on the error message in the question, `strlen` performs some checks for a valid pointer before it starts. If `getenv` is returning pointers to some part of memory reserved by the OS for environment variables, it might trigger the checks while still being a valid pointer.

Comment: @Mark: Oho! You may be right. +1 for spotting that. On my Linux box, `strlen` works as expected for a valid `getenv`-returned value, though.

Comment: @MarkRansom: "strlen performs some checks". It doesn't, AFAIK: `printf("%d\n", strlen(0));` kills application on both msvc/gcc-mingw. YOu're free to check if that's standard-conforming.

Comment: @SigTerm, after a bit of Googling I concede the point. The error message is coming from Valgrind, not strlen. The part I don't get is why it's complaining about address 0x1, not 0x0.